# Медленный старт NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Первый запуск NHibernate (версия 3.3) занимает порядка 4 секунды.

Для теста использую консольное приложение с одной сущностью, один hbm.xml-файл и один hibernate.cfg.xml.

Как видно из dotTrace-снапшота ниже все основное время съедают три действия: Configuration..ctor (2,043 s), BuildSessionFactory (1.211) и AddAssembly (678 s).

Хотелось бы узнать - четыре секунды это приемлемо для первого запуска NHibernate и возможно ли как-то с этим бороться?

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.aspx

Comment: На сколько я правильно понимаю материал по данный ссылке, то основная идея в том, чтобы сериализовать файл конфигурации если не было в нем никаких изменений. Но, по-моему, NHibernate 3.3 и так выполняет серриализацию файла конфигурации. Скрин добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помойму приемлимо, т.к. ему нужно замапить все сущьности, настроить подключения ну и вообще собратся с мыслями :) 
BuildSessionFactory - очень дорогостоящая операция, и обычно SessionFactory хранится как синглтон.